# How to track two colors in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm building this window screen:

[image]

I want to use yellow color marker to determine the gesture touch inside play rectangle and I want green color marker to determine the gesture touch inside quit rectangle. 
However, I wrote this code:

```
//Capture a temporary image from the camera
Mat imgTmp;
cap.read(imgTmp);

//Create a black image with the size as the camera output
Mat imgLines = Mat::zeros(imgTmp.size(), CV_8UC3);;

while (true)
{
    Mat frame;

    bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

    if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
    {
        cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream" << endl;
        break;
    }

    //tracking colors
    Mat imgHSV;

    cvtColor(frame, imgHSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV); //Convert the captured frame from BGR to HSV

    Mat imgThresholded;

    inRange(imgHSV, Scalar(ylowH, ylowS, ylowV), Scalar(yhighH, yhighS, yhighV), imgThresholded); //Threshold the image
    inRange(imgHSV, Scalar(glowH, glowS, glowV), Scalar(ghighH, ghighS, ghighV), imgThresholded);

    //morphological opening (removes small objects from the foreground)
    erode(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
    dilate(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));

    //morphological closing (removes small holes from the foreground)
    dilate(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
    erode(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));

    //Calculate the moments of the thresholded image
    Moments oMoments = moments(imgThresholded);

    double dM01 = oMoments.m01;
    double dM10 = oMoments.m10;
    double dArea = oMoments.m00;

    // if the area <= 10000, I consider that the there are no object in the image and it's because of the noise, the area is not zero 
    if (dArea > 10000)
    {
        //calculate the position of the ball
        int posX = dM10 / dArea;
        int posY = dM01 / dArea;
```

But it is tracking only green color while both green and yellow color are inside camera field of view. How to track multiple color and found their interaction at certain coordinate at screen (like mouse functioning)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is tracking only the green colour object because you use only one `cv::Mat` object to store the binary thresholded image. In your code, you threshold the image using yellow values and store it to `cv::Mat imgThresholded`. But after this, you threshold the original image with green colour and store it to the same variable. This operation overrides the information from the earlier thresholding. The same happens with the morphological operations. To fix, simply use two matrices

```
Mat imgThreshYellow
Mat imgThreshGreen

inRange(imgHSV, Scalar(ylowH, ylowS, ylowV), Scalar(yhighH, yhighS, yhighV), imgThreshYellow); //Threshold the image
inRange(imgHSV, Scalar(glowH, glowS, glowV), Scalar(ghighH, ghighS, ghighV), imgThreshGreen);
```

Obviously, you need to also change the morphological operations to operate on the respective correct binary image matrices, and compute the moments of the images for both colours separately.